# Populate .data() with $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate `$('div').data()` through JSON. It works fine with `JQuery.parseJSON` but not with `$.getJSON`.

```
// works as expected
$('div').data('dat', { xmin: '-10', xmax: 40 });
$('div').data('dat', jQuery.parseJSON('{"bbx" : {"xmin" : "-10", "xmax" : "40"}}'));

// doesnt work
$('div').data('dat', $.getJSON("init.php", function(json) {return(json);}));
```

Comment: It's asynchronous, so no, that won't work? On the other hand, setting the data inside the callback function of getJSON would work just fine, but not the other way around.

Comment: $.getJSON() is async see Sudhir's answer

Comment: Maybe dollar sign is used by another framework? Try `jQuery.getJSON`

Comment: This might help: [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9922250/1195891)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because getJSON is an async operation. The original statement is now out of scope by the time your success function executes.

Can you not do it this way ?

```
$.getJSON("init.php", function (json) {
    $('div').data('dat', json);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you could do:

```
$.getJSON("init.php", function(json) {
    $('div').data('dat', json);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`getJSON` is an ajax call which is asyncronous, so the function itself doesn't return anything, it just calls the appropriate callback, so you could do this instead:

```
$.getJSON("init.php", function(json){
    $('div').data('dat', json);
})
```

Note: `$.get` will retrieve the JSON as a string and won't parse it unlike `getJSON`, so if you want to store the JSON as a string then use `$.get`. Storing the parsed object will work as well (by using `getJSON`).

Comment: "get will retrieve the JSON as a string and won't parse it unlike getJSON" That's a good point!

Answer (score 2):

You can also store data in array format:

```
$.getJSON('init.php', function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('div').data('dat', items)
});
```