# modal:true not working in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I know this question is asked already but I am not finding solution for this

Here is my jquery code:

```
    function openArmoryDialog(id) {
        var divID = $("#ArmoryDialogDiv");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/aoa_mvc/armory/Detail/" + id,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(divID).html(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                  $(divID).html(data);
            },
            complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#ArmoryDialogDiv').dialog({
                    width: 500,
                    modal:true // This is not working
                });

            }
        });   
    }
```

I don't know why modal popup is not opening, I have tried many solutions but none is working for me

**I included needed css file**

Comment: What is your error getting in console?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML - we can't see that there is a div with that ID. Also is it definitely the ONLY div with that ID? Also please show your includes, we can't tell that jQuery or jQuery UI is included.

Comment: Did you try to see the page on FireFox with FireBug enabled?

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ jquery-1.9.1.js:8492
TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Comment: `var divID = $("#ArmoryDialogDiv");` and `$(divID)` - while I think jQuery checks and allows that to work, one of the `$()`s is redundant.

Comment: You have not mentioned if you have included the jquery ui library.

Comment: Hi Saurabh,

In my point of View you already defined ` var divID = $("#ArmoryDialogDiv");` then why your again using "$(divID)"? Thats not needed you can just use divID instead.
And Please sure about adding the right JQuery library.
Make sure you using the div ID **#ArmoryDialogDiv** for only one time in the page.
If you post your code HTML we can look what goes wrong, above all my suggestions to check the problem. And look @ here for more info about your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589393/cannot-make-http-request-javascript-ns-error-failure

Comment: The code, as you have posted it, is correct. The problem is elsewhere. Possible investigation: Does your DOM contain an element with `id=ArmoryDialogDiv`? Can you see the `GET` request on the server? off-topic:  You should also keep in mind `divID.html(dataFromServer)` is a XSS vulnerability