# get html input field value from Cross-Domain using jsonp

Tags: html, cross-domain, jsonp

Trying to retrieve the value of a input field in a external site's webpage. They wont change the headers. So been told to use Jsonp. Never used this. Anyone have any examples or can point me in the right direction?

Outline:
External Site:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ImHiddenGetMe" value="Get Me If You Can">
```

Cannot use ajax/jquery as they wont change the headers to allow the cross domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-a-particular-value-by-injecting-it-i

Comment: "But source must be aware that you want it to call function passed as callback parameter to it." - It isn't.

Comment: Do you have access to the other server, i.e. can you configure it?

Comment: Nope I requested they change the headers so I could just use jquery and ajax, they said no. I've built a C# application that just grabs the info and displays for the user who needs the info but apparently its not tidy and they want it embedded to our script. They suggested I use JSONP never used it, does it require the server to postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) the other server must provide an interface to it. For example: The other server must provide an URL like

```
http://other.com/getvalue?jsonp=callbackFunction
```

This URL must sent JavaScript code like

```
callbackFunction({ value: "Get Me If You Can" })
```

If the other server does not provide such an interface and do not provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header necessary for [Cross origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) you cannot load the other site via AJAX.

But you can always program a [crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) which stores the value periodically on your server (where you can use it). Please respect the other server's [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) in this case.