# How to get json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am getting the values from database in php and encoded the retrieved values to json data format.

php code:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM theater';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
echo json_encode($row) "\r\n"; 
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

output:

```
{"id":"11","region":"Central","cord_latitude":"12.9237","cord_longitude":"77.5535"}
```

now i need to get only some values from the json data to javascript. 
I need only cord_latitude and cord_longitude values in javascript
how can i get those values in javascript?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Get JSon using PHP URL and parse it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-it-in-a-div-as-plain-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_data = '{"id":"11","region":"Central","cord_latitude":"12.9237","cord_longitude":"77.5535"}';
    var parsed_data = JSON.parse(json_data);

    console.log('long: ' + parsed_data.cord_longitude)
    console.log('lat: ' + parsed_data.cord_latitude)
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to switch your code around a bit, you are logging your latitude after your longitude, and the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Parse your json encoded string in javascript:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo json_encode($row) "\r\n";
```

To:

```
echo json_encode(array("cord_latitude" => $row["cord_latitude"], "cord_longitude" => $row["cord_longitude"]));
```

And then use [JSON.parse();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
json = 'YOUR JSON STRING'
theater = JSON.parse(json);

console.log('Longitude: ' + theater.cord_longitude)
console.log('Latitude: ' + theater.cord_latitude)
```

This way only those 2 fields will go over the line, resulting in less trafic and thus faster loading.