# json nested arrays error

Tags: javascript, json

hey before i start with the main question i should state that the .json file is an external file in the same folder with .html files.I do not know if it helps but i am new to json.
My questions are 
1) why jsfiddle throws throws errors  at  `"papadopoulos_antonis": [{`
  `"papadopoulos_stauros":=[{`
   `"maria_anagnostou":= [{`
2) is it right to do `<link src=.../>` to read json file?

Thanks

```js
//this is in a json external file.the file is in the same folder with other html files
   users = [

"papadopoulos_antonis": [{
fname: 'Παπαδόπουλος Αντώνης',
field1: 'Συντήρηση Αυτοκινήτου',
field2: 'Ορειβατικός εξοπλισμός',
field3: 'Μάθημα Καράτε',
field4: ''
}],

"papadopoulos_stauros":[{
fname: 'Παπαδόπουλος Σταύρος',
field1: 'Αναψυκτικά',
field2: 'Αλκοολούχα ποτά',
field3: 'Εξοδα καυσίμων',
field4: ''
}],

"maria_anagnostou": [{
fname: 'Αναγνώστου Μαρία',
field1: 'Διαφήμιση επιχείρησης',
field2: 'Τεχνικός επιχείρησης',
field3: 'Μηχανικός επιχείρησης',
feild4: ''
}] 
]


function jsonObjs(select) {
  
  var = JSONobject = JSON.parse(users);
  alert(users.papadopoulos_antonis[fname]);
  if (select == 1) {
    alert(users.papadopoulos_antonis[fname]);
  } else if (select == 2) {
    alert(users.papadopoulos_stauros[fname]);
  } else if (select == 3) {

  }
}
```

```html
<link src="formMembers.json" type="text/javascript"/>


    <select id="selectCategory" onchange="jsonObjs(this)">
        <option>Επιλογή...</option>
        <option>Παπαδόπουλος Αντώνης</option>
        <option>Παπαδόπουλος Σταύρος</option>
        <option>Αναγνώστου Μαρία</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: `fname: 'Αναγνώστου Μαρία'.` <<< `.` instead of `,`

Comment: *"this is in a json external file"* That is not valid JSON. It's simply a file containing JavaScript. *"is it right to do `<link src=.../>` to read json file?"* No. JavaScript is included via `<script>` tags. (real) JSON files cannot be included via HTML tags.

Comment: I think you should learn more about arrays and objects in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: then how  if not link tag ?

Comment: As I said you cannot include JSON files via HTML. However, you don't have JSON, you have JavaScript, so just use a `<script>` element.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` **an invalid JSON will not work.**

`users = [` is an array and an array should look like:

```
users = ["val", "val", "val"]
```

*instead you have:*

```
users = [prop:"val", prop:"val", prop:"val"]
```

which should instead be an Object:

```
users = {prop:"val", prop:"val", prop:"val"} // Plain Object (not valid JSON)
```

Fix your `.`>>>`,` typo.
For a valid JSON use double-quotes:

```
{
    "papadopoulos_antonis": {
        "fname": "ΠαπαδόπουλοςΑντώνης",
        "field1": "ΣυντήρησηΑυτοκινήτου",
        "field2": "Ορειβατικόςεξοπλισμός",
        "field3": "ΜάθημαΚαράτε",
        "field4": ""
    },
    "papadopoulos_stauros": {
        "fname": "ΠαπαδόπουλοςΣταύρος",
        "field1": "Αναψυκτικά",
        "field2": "Αλκοολούχαποτά",
        "field3": "Εξοδακαυσίμων",
        "field4": ""
    },
    "maria_anagnostou": {
        "fname": "ΑναγνώστουΜαρία",
        "field1": "Διαφήμισηεπιχείρησης",
        "field2": "Τεχνικόςεπιχείρησης",
        "field3": "Μηχανικόςεπιχείρησης",
        "feild4": ""
    }
}
```

**// Valid JSON** http://jsonlint.com/

To get your JSON file see: [Get JSON data from external URL and display it in a div as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-it-in-a-div-as-plain-text)

If you want to treat your "JSON" like an JS object than yes, you can call it using

```
<script src="myJson.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(users); // Works
</script>
```

Comment: It's still not JSON though, so `JSON.parse(users)` will throw and `<link src=.../>` won't work either.

Comment: @FelixKling well, for a valid JSON see above

Comment: to make it clear i want a json file  so maybe the <link is not right

Comment: @MilsZ no, link is not right. Use AJAX or JSONP. I'll show you in a demo

Comment: the problem is i have only 4 hours to solve this and do other things until the project finishes and i do not have time to read so many things...
But json is corrent but throws error   at 
function jsonObjs(select) {  ---expected '(End)' and instead show function