# Javascript fails to fetch Json data from url

Tags: javascript, json, jqxhr

I am trying to fetch json data from my server using Javascript, and I followed the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587512/2867094). But It doesn't work for me. And I found out that xhr.onload = function() not run in my case. How to figure it out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
   <script>
       var getJSON = function(url) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('get', url, true);
       xhr.responseType = 'json';
       xhr.onload = function() {
       var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
         resolve(xhr.response);
       } else {
         reject(status);
       }
    };
       xhr.send();
     });
       };

  getJSON('http://qlin.parseapp.com/version2/myres.txt').then(function(data) {
alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
       }, function(status) { //error detection....
         alert('Something went wrong.');
       });
       </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Is the code run from http://qlin.parseapp.com ? If not you need to enable CORS

Comment: Thank. It works when I deploy it on qlin server.

Comment: Most of the time you have to enable CORS on the server. I recommend using a simple Node.JS/[Express](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) server to try to do this functionality.