# How to load external JSON with a variable defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How to load data from external json file(.json) which contains a variable defined in it.

```
var mainObject= {"main":[{key1:value2}, {key2:value2}]}
```

What is the method to call `mainObject` vaiable using **jquery** or **javascript**?

Comment: that's not JSON - that's simply javascript - load it using script tag

Comment: But is there a way to call the mainObject variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get JSON data from external URL and display it in a div as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-it-in-a-div-as-plain-text)

Comment: Is that what the JSON looks like. Because that's not valid JSON. Like Jaromanda said, that's actual javascript.

Comment: @Jaideep pl provide the details on what you tried.

Comment: sorry, is the line of "code" the content of the external file?

Comment: @Jaromanda X - Yes it is...

Comment: QRaviprakash -  Here it is

function loadJSON()
{
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {

 var JSONObject = mainObject;

// The JSONObject variable now contains the data structure and can be accessed as JSONObject.firstName and
// JSONObject.lastName. Assign the object members to the DOM elements FirstName and LastName so that they get
// displayed on the page
   document.getElementsByClassName("Wrapper").innerHTML = JSONObject;
  }
  }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","json.json",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
  var jsonData=JSON.parse(mainObject);

 var data=jsonData.main;
 console.log(data[0].key1);
 console.log(data[1].key2);
```

Comment: But how to link it to .json file? Is it ok to give src in script tag?

Comment: No you cant read/Write external json file.U should store it in localstorage or u need to read it online.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have json data in mainObject so calling in javascript like this

```
console.log(mainObject[0].key1);
```

As the jQuery API says: "Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request."

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
So you cannot load a local file with that function.

Answer (score 0):

Either $.ajax or $.get to grab a json file. Basically you can do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.json',
    method: 'GET'
}).success(function(data){
    var property = JSON.parse(data).property;
});
```

This is assuming that the json file is properly formatted. A valid JSON file with your data would look more like:

```
{
    "main": [
    {
        "key1": "value1"
    }, 
    {
        "key2": "value2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: But here I have to remove the variable isn't it? What if I want to call the variable iself?

Comment: In this scenario, the data variable is what you use. Basically ` data = {"main":[{key1:value2}, {key2:value2}]} ` inside of the success callback. It contains the array of objects you set in the JSON file. The mainObject you are showing, is not valid JSON, it is JavaScript, as others have said. To get an object in that format, you would have to use a module loader like RequireJS,  which is more complex or load it via a script tag after the main logic.