# How should I call my internal API from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an API in my app, how can I call the API in a JS script when I don't have a URL and I'm still in development?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-it-in-a-div-as-plain-text etc

Comment: @nogad I know how to process the JSON file once I get it. But I don't know how can I call my API since it's internal and I don't have a URL to pass to JS. Thanks

Comment: Hard to make any sense out of this question

Comment: `it's internal` ... you mean the server isn't exposed to the internet?

Comment: that link tells you HOW to get it

Comment: I'm sorry @charlietfl I probably explained it in a bad way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not specify the domain name as part of the API's URL and deploy the JavaScript application to the same domain/port as the PHP API. You may have to do this anyway for security reasons (look up CORS).

So, if you call your API endpoint at `/api/endpoint` from your application deployed at `/app`, you will be independent of the domain, no matter if you are working locally

```
http://localhost:8080/app
http://localhost:8080/api/endpoint
```

, or in production

```
https://example.com/app
https://example.com/api/endpoint
```

Comment: I had tried this but I didn't get it working, I think I didn't put the http:// for some reason. Stupid of me. Cheers mate